# SQL Server : Insert Values into a Table with one Dynamic Query, constants, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, sql-insert, dynamic-sql

I have the following query that inserts some values into one table and this is working:

```
INSERT INTO Table(id, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4)
 SELECT (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'ddMMyyyy') +@MAINFIELD+@FIELDTYPE), @MAINFIELD, date , @ColumnName, '0'
FROM kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  @TABLENAME and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = @CurrentPosition
```

This is working fine. The problem comes when I want to insert a new value into the table and this value is obtained from a Dynamic Query:

This is the query which works separately (the variable is defined)

```
EXEC ('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]')
```

If I want to include it in the insert query however I don't think this is possible. At least it is not compiling for me:

```
INSERT INTO Table(id, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, **field_5**)
 SELECT (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'ddMMyyyy') +@MAINFIELD+@FIELDTYPE), @MAINFIELD, date , @ColumnName, '0', **EXEC ('SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]')**
FROM kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  @TABLENAME and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = @CurrentPosition
```

Maybe is there a better solution to include this Dynamic query in the insert clause?

Edit: After Nisarg comments and support I adapted the query:

```
set @MAINFIELD=  CAST(@MAINCURRENCY AS VARCHAR);
set @FIELDTYPE=  CAST(@RATETYPE AS VARCHAR);
SET @ColumnName = CAST(@ColumnName AS VARCHAR)
SET @CurrentPosition = CAST(@CurrentPosition AS INT)
EXEC( 'INSERT INTO Devisen_geldkurs(devisen_geldkurs, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5) 
SELECT (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   ''ddMMyyyy'') +''@MAINFIELD''+''@FIELDTYPE''), "@MAINFIELD", date , "@ColumnName", ''0'', 
    SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table] from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  "Imported_Table" and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = ''@CurrentPosition''')
```

The only problem it seems that is in the SELECT clause:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

I also removed one of the following :  f`rom kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table] FROM kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]` . It was written twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just write a dynamic query in the middle of a query. But you could convert the entire query into a dynamic query:

```
EXEC( 'INSERT INTO Table(id, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5) 
SELECT (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   ''ddMMyyyy'') +@MAINFIELD+@FIELDTYPE), @MAINFIELD, date , @ColumnName, ''0'', 
    SELECT '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table] FROM kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table] 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  @TABLENAME and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = @CurrentPosition')
```

Please do check by `PRINT`ing it first though, in order to ensure that the query does not have any syntax errors.

Also, you should avoid using `EXEC`. Instead you could use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) which provides better protection against SQL injection for dynamic queries.

### Update

I missed to wrap the `SELECT` subquery in brackets earlier. Here's how it should be. Note the `(SELECT TOP 1 '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]) as field_5` statement in line 7 below:

```
set @MAINFIELD=  CAST(@MAINCURRENCY AS VARCHAR);
set @FIELDTYPE=  CAST(@RATETYPE AS VARCHAR);
SET @ColumnName = CAST(@ColumnName AS VARCHAR)
SET @CurrentPosition = CAST(@CurrentPosition AS INT)
EXEC( 'INSERT INTO Devisen_geldkurs(devisen_geldkurs, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5) 
SELECT (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   ''ddMMyyyy'') +''@MAINFIELD''+''@FIELDTYPE''), "@MAINFIELD", date , "@ColumnName", ''0'', 
    (SELECT TOP 1 '+@ColumnName+' from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]) as field_5
    from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  "Imported_Table" and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = ''@CurrentPosition''')
```

Alternatively, since you are using a dynamic query, the following should work as well. I've removed the subquery, and appended the field name in the query.

```
set @MAINFIELD=  CAST(@MAINCURRENCY AS VARCHAR);
set @FIELDTYPE=  CAST(@RATETYPE AS VARCHAR);
SET @ColumnName = CAST(@ColumnName AS VARCHAR)
SET @CurrentPosition = CAST(@CurrentPosition AS INT)
EXEC( 'INSERT INTO Devisen_geldkurs(devisen_geldkurs, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5) 
SELECT (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   ''ddMMyyyy'') +''@MAINFIELD''+''@FIELDTYPE''), "@MAINFIELD", date , "@ColumnName", ''0'', '+@ColumnName+'

from kat.[dbo].[Imported_Table]
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  "Imported_Table" and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = ''@CurrentPosition''')
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for the Query transformation and for the tip regarding sp_executesql. However when trying to run the new query (also just trying to select before inserting) all the variables defined are not detected anymore : @MAINFIELD, FIELDTYPE...

Comment: hmm I didn't notice them earlier. There are two ways to go about it: (1) Either append them to query as varchar and use `EXEC` to execute the query, or (2) Pass them as parameters in `sp_executesql`

Comment: Hi, Regarding the first option you mean to convertthe variable into Varchar before executing the query? Maybe  something like this? set @MAINFIELD='+@MAINFIELD+'

Comment: @Katherine99 Yes, that should work. Just ensure that you cast the variables to `varchar` of appropriate size before appending to the query. Also, you'd need to insert single quotes around the variables in the query if they are supposed to be string. So, as I mentioned, it is best to `PRINT` the query before running it to avoid syntax issues.

Comment: thanks again. This seems to work (I updated the query in the main topic) , but the select subquery does not seem to work.

Comment: I missed to wrap it in `()` brackets. Also, note that I've added `TOP 1` and `as field_5` there, assuming you expect there to be only one result. They should not be necessary, but having those generally helps avoid unexpected errors.

Comment: Hi Nisarg, Because of the complexity of the query I decided finally to go for the option of 
sp_executesql. I converted the query based on this and it seems to work. At the moment the query runs but inserts nothing because due to the ' ' separator it does not detect the table name. I hope a find the solution for this and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use INSERT EXEC. You must have table's variable declared inside and outside dynamic query. 
At the end of dynamic query just select from table variable and insert resultset into outside table variable

```
DECLARE @table SomeTable ( ID INT ) 

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(120) = 'declare @table  SomeTable (id int) 
                                insert into @table  values(1),(2) 
                                select * from @table '

INSERT INTO @table 
EXEC(@query)

SELECT * FROM @table
```